# Spring Batch Item Read Listener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

How to track when FlatFileItemReader returns null (i.e. encounters end of the flat file).

ItemReadListener is not working.

Comment: how ItemReadListener is not working? Do you have some sample code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Listener doesn't work because its purpose is to track read elements not EOF.
If you want to track EOF you have to write a `ItemReader` delegate using read reader as delegate, override [`ItemReader.read()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html#read--) check for null and do whatever you want.